# Why does Prolog skip all further if statements in recursion if one of them fails?

Tags: if-statement, recursion, prolog

The point of the program is to calculate the sum of all even numbers in a list of integers.

```
    is_even(Q):- Q mod 2 =:= 0.  

    sum_even([],0).
    sum_even([A|L],X) :-  sum_even(L,X1) -> is_even(A) -> X is X1 + A .
```

Whenever the is_even predicate succeeds there is no problem, it normally goes back to calculate the sum. However when the number is not even and is_even checks it, it fails, goes back to the recursion and fails everything that follows, doesn't even check if the number is even anymore and just returns false. In a list full of even numbers it works as intended, it returns the sum of all numbers in the  list. [This here is the trace of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iTsN.png)

Comment: (The answer to your question is that you haven't coded any handling for odd numbers. Rather than code which sums the even numbers in a list, you've written code which sums a list of only even numbers. Then when you give a list with odd numbers, Prolog "returns false" telling you that your code has no solutions possible for that list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an accumulator with tail-end recursion is fastest:

```
is_even(N) :-
    N mod 2 =:= 0.

sum_even(Lst, Sum) :-
    sum_even_(Lst, 0, Sum).

sum_even_([], Sum, Sum).
sum_even_([H|T], Upto, Sum) :-
    (   is_even(H) ->
        Upto1 is Upto + H
    ;   Upto1 = Upto
    ),
    sum_even_(T, Upto1, Sum).


sum_even_slow([], 0).
sum_even_slow([H|T], Sum) :-
    sum_even_slow(T, Sum0),
    (   is_even(H) ->
        Sum is Sum0 + H
    ;   Sum = Sum0
    ).
```

Performance comparison in swi-prolog:

```
?- numlist(1, 1_000_000, L), time(sum_even(L, Sum)).
% 4,000,002 inferences, 0.765 CPU in 0.759 seconds (101% CPU, 5228211 Lips)
Sum = 250000500000.

?- numlist(1, 1_000_000, L), time(sum_even_slow(L, Sum)).
% 4,000,001 inferences, 4.062 CPU in 4.023 seconds (101% CPU, 984755 Lips)
Sum = 250000500000.
```

Comment: Thanks, I only needed the slow version since the exercise demands that I use /2 but, yea turns out all I needed to do was X is X1 when the if statement failed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_even(X, Buffer, Sum) :-
    (0 =:= X mod 2 -> 
        Sum is Buffer + X
    ;   Sum = Buffer).
```

Used with [`foldl(add_even, Nums, 0, Sum)`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=foldl/4) is about as fast as brebs' tail recursion. Using [SWISH Online](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/):

```
?- numlist(1, 1_000_000, _L), time(sum_even(_L, Sum)).
4,000,002 inferences, 0.699 CPU in 0.699 seconds (100% CPU, 5724382 Lips)
Sum = 250000500000

?- numlist(1, 1_000_000, _L), time(foldl(add_even, _L, 0, Sum)).
4,000,002 inferences, 0.712 CPU in 0.712 seconds (100% CPU, 5621314 Lips)
Sum = 250000500000
```

(I am curious, if they both do exactly 4,000,002 inferences how come the sum_even seems to get higher LIPS throughput and finish slightly faster?)

Comment: Aside: Dyalog APL does 100M in 320ms, making it some 200x faster. And 1 line of code instead of 5 or 9. And no higher-order predicates, linked lists, recursion, if/else branching, and is an interpreted language. `]runtime '{+/ (0=2|⍵)/⍵} ⍳ 1e8'`

Comment: Some inferences are quicker than others - an extreme example: `numlist(1, 9_000_000, L1), numlist(1, 9_000_000, L2), writeln("checking"), time(L1 = L2).` gives 4 Lips.

Comment: Using Prolog to add some numbers, is like using Marvin to park cars at Milliways :-)

Comment: @brebs "Here I am, brain the size of a planet, and they ask me to sum even numbers. Call that job satisfaction? And don't get me started on the diodes all down my left side..." :-)

Answer (score 0):

The reason that this

```
is_even(Q):- Q mod 2 =:= 0.  

sum_even([],0).
sum_even([A|L],X) :- sum_even(L,X1) -> is_even(A) -> X is X1 + A .
```

fails when there's odd numbers in the list is that `'->'/2`, the "implies" operator, is a *soft cut*. It eliminates the choice point. That means that backtracking into it fails, thus unwinding the whole thing and failing the entire predicate.

Your code is roughly equivalent to

```
sum_even([],0).
sum_even([A|L],X) :- sum_even(L,X1), !, is_even(A), !, X is X1 + A .
```

You need to

- Eliminate the `'->'/2` — it's not necessary the ',' operator is the AND operator, and
- Provide an alternative to handle the case when an item is odd.

For instance, you could say this:

```
is_even( Q ) :- Q mod 2 =:= 0.  

sum_even( []    , 0 ) .
sum_even( [A|L] , X ) :-
  sum_even(L,X1),
  ( is_even(A) ->
      X is X1 + A
    ;
      X is X1
  ) .
```

Or something like this:

```
is_even( Q ) :- Q mod 2 =:= 0.  

sum_even( []    , 0 ) .
sum_even( [A|L] , X ) :-
  sum_even(L,X1),
  add_even(A,X1,X) .

add_even(X,Y,Z) :- is_even(X), !, Z is X + Y .
add_even(_,Z,Z) .
```

But the easiest, faster way is to use a helper predicate that carries the extra state. The above predicates will die with a stack overflow given a sufficiently long list. This will not: Prolog has TRO (tail recursion optimization) built in, which effectively turns the recursive call into iteration by reusing the stack frame, so it can handle recursion of any depth:

```
sum_even( Xs , S ) :- sum_even(Xs,0,S) .

sum_even( []     , S , S ) .
sum_even( [X|Xs] , T , S ) :- is_even(X), !, T1 is T+X, sum_even(Xs,T1,S) .

is_even( Q ) :- Q mod 2 =:= 0.
```